# Next.js, Express.js app's apis running in development but status 404 in production

Tags: express, nginx, next.js, production

I have deployed nextjs, expressjs application on production but I am getting 404 for all apis. 
I have pages that works fine

```
  var session = require('express-session');
  var passport = require('passport');
  const KnexSessionStore = require('connect-session-knex')(session);
  const knex  = require('./db/knex.js');
  const authMid = require('./config/utils')


  const app = express();
  app.use(compression())
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

  // sesstion
  const store = new KnexSessionStore({
    knex: knex,
    tablename: 'sessions' // optional. Defaults to 'sessions'
  });

  app.use(session({
    name: 'connect.sid',
    store: store,
    secret: 'somesupersecretkey',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 
    },
    // cookie: { secure: false }
  }));


  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  require("./config/passport");
  require("./config/passport_fb");
  require("./config/passport_google");
  var routes = require('./routes/index');
  routes.mp_routes(app);

  // Server-side
  const route = pathMatch();


  // pages set up
  // private & public
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/index', req.query)
  })

  app.get('/questions', (req, res) => {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/questions', req.query)
  })
```

And my routes/index.js file looks like

```
module.exports.mp_routes = (app) => {
  app.use('/api/v1', questionsRoutes),
  app.use('/api/v1', answersRoutes)
}
```

Everything nextjs pages and express apis do work fine in development. I don't have to do anything but on production pages do work but all apis say status 404. How do i get fixed

Comment: What production environment are you using? If you are using AWS EC2 you have to expose a port and map the port to your production server port using pm2 or some script to keep the environment to run and be alive

Comment: I have deployed on digital ocean's droplet, This entire application is running on port 3000. And I am using pm2 to keep server running. But that's not problem. The problem is inside app.prepare() fuction. Where i have defined all my pages route like I have explained in my question. Pages I can see properly and all my apis have a prefix of '/api/v1'. when I am visiting let's say https://example.com/api/v1/questions. It says 404 but for nextjs pages it works absolutely fine

Comment: I have done npm run build and followed by next start